# How to create several ListTile inside a List and prompt them out in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, web

Below is the code what I did, but it perform nothing.

```
class _MenuListState extends State<MenuList> {

  List<ListTile> menu = [
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
      title: Text('Playlists'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.send),
      title: Text('Menu...'),
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
      title: Text('Logout'),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: menu.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final menuList = menu[index];
          
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As mentioned as title, how can I let the code perform that the screen prompt out all the ListTile inside the List?

Comment: itemBuilder needs to return a widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Return the widget in itemBuilder**

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: menu.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return menu[index];

        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Just need to Return menuListItem**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class MenuList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MenuListState createState() => _MenuListState();
    }
    
    class _MenuListState extends State<MenuList> {
      List<ListTile> menu = [
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.featured_play_list),
          title: Text('Playlists'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.send),
          title: Text('Menu...'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
          title: Text('Logout'),
        ),
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: menu.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final menuListItem = menu[index];
              return menuListItem;
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```